# Are nonfiction writers, that avoid the use of footnotes/endnotes, respected by the academic community?

Tags: citations, plagiarism, books, lecture-notes

I've seen books of Jared Diamond (biogeographer) and other fine nonfiction writers, that don't use any references or footnotes/endnotes - not even bibliography. Instead, they put a "for further readings" section at the end, where they "talk" about related books, papers and articles, and they don't seem to express directly that they used any of those books for their writing.

1. Is that enough to be "respected" (or recommended to friends or family) by the academic community?
2. Doesn't he incur in plagiarism in any way?
3. What method would you use if you were writing for the popular?

Comment: There is a difference between 'popular' (meant for a wide audience) and 'scholarly' (meant for other academics). Which are you writing?

Comment: Popular, 100%, but I would also like to be "accepted" (not read) by scholars and academics.

Comment: I voted to close because this question is about the opinion of the writing community (not the academic community) on the writing of nonacademic books.

Comment: Academic books need those in-text citations.

Comment: You are right. I'm actually asking for the opinion of the academic community on Diamond's (and alikes) way of "adding references". I've restructured the whole question to be clear. Thank you for the observation.

Comment: Question 1 is unclear. What does "validity" mean here? Academics have a notion of validity of research articles, but that obviously doesn't apply here.

Comment: With validity I mean if you would recommend it to friends and family. I've edited the question one last time. It seems to be a topic that no one gives attention to. I haven't found an answer online. A lot of nonfiction writers with academic backgrounds are avoiding notes and references with the "further readings" option, which I believe incurs in plagiarism and ethical harm (according to standards). They even have won Pulitzer Prices... So, if both the popular and academics don´t care about it, maybe it's just an old ethical practice that today is no longer needed.

Comment: @RichardF. This is not really your question, but from what I can tell, Diamond isn't all that respected by the academic community. See, e.g. here: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/2mkcc3/how_do_modern_historians_and_history/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not address an attribute of a *person* (in this case: J. Diamond), but of a *publication* - or to be more precise, of the *social system* (e.g. system of scientific publications, system of popular books).

If X writes a paper for a scholarly journal, X needs to use footnotes or in-text citations because the scientific system requires the ability to trace the origins behind a statement. Otherwise, the system will reject the paper (through peer-reviewers and editors).

But if X writes for a popular press, such references are not required; editors may even reject book proposals if they seem 'too scientific'.

Thus, Jared Diamond uses footnotes or in-text references when he writes for an academic journal ([such as this paper for the journal *Biological Conservation*](http://www.jareddiamond.org/Jared_Diamond/Further_Reading_files/Diamond%201975.pdf)). And Google Scholar tells us that this peer-reviewed paper has been cited more than 2.000 times in scholarly works. There therefore seems to be no lack of respect for Diamond's scientific outputs within the scientific system.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see an issue in many (most?) cases. Especially if they are writing for a popular rather than academic audience. The question is the tradeoff between readability and the need for specificity in such works. Let me give an example.

While I'm a mathematician who taught CS until retirement, I read quite a lot of books on anthropology and archaeology. I don't read scientific papers, but try to follow advances as reported in the press as they occur.

There are two kinds of books. One in which an author will give a narrative covering what is known about a topic (say early humans in what became North America) without inline citations. These can be very readable, I find. There is no danger of assuming plagiarism since the author(s) give the further reading section which lists the source. Most of the ideas presented are "in their own words" rather than copied from sources, and most represent a scientific consensus along with some information about where the consensus breaks down.

Other authors, writing on the same topic use a large number of inline citations, with footnotes or (usually) endnotes. I find these to be much harder to follow and it is often necessary to go to the endnote as more is presented there than just the source, such as a few additional ideas. They may be a bit more precise, but for the audience, not essentially so.

So, in some sense, your question is, whether popularizers of science are respected or not. Some are, others not, of course. Great story tellers are valued, I guess. But it is a choice that an author makes. The ones I read are careful not to plagiarize, but are a bit less specific about which ideas come from which source. However, once a scientific consensus is achieved, even with some dissent, it seems less vital for these types of work. The "further reading" gives you a sense about how the consensus arose.

But if you are writing at the edge of the known world, the rules about citation are much more vital, since a consensus has not yet emerged.